# How to create "Add to apple wallet" button using PKAddPassButton for passes with localisation

Tags: ios, swift, wallet, passkit

In my iOS project I have a screen which allows the user to create apple passes and add it to the wallet. Apple recommends creating "Add to apple wallet" button using  PKAddPassButton. When I tried creating apple pass using following code:

```
let passButton =  PKAddPassButton(addPassButtonStyle: PKAddPassButtonStyle.black)
passButton.frame = CGRect(x:45.0, y: 340.0, width: 320, height: 50)
view.addSubview(passButton)
```

[image]

Button has got couple of issues:

1. Wallet image is not visible.
2. Even after changing the language at device level won't localise the text.

Should I use some custom UIButton to achieve this?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer, I was testing the code on simulator.When tested the same on device it worked and also localisation is taken care by iOS. If the user changes device language in settings it directly gets reflected in "Add to Apple wallet button".

Comment: what about i want to change the locale but not according the device language in settings?

Comment: In that case you can make use of image assets from apple , check your locale language and create a custom button with corresponding image.

Comment: For me as well Wallet image is not visible on the button...

Answer (score 1):

1. The wallet image will be visible when running on real device only, it won't come on simulator.
2. For localisation of this PKAddPassButton, the iOS handles it automatically based on the device language and region settings.