# How to add "Add to Apple Wallet" button with PKAddPassButton - swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wallet

Sorry if this sounds dumb, complete swift noob here,

I'm trying to create the "Add to Apple Wallet" button. But I can't figure out how. I've tried the code snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49773184/how-to-create-add-to-apple-wallet-button-using-pkaddpassbutton-for-passes-with), but nothing showed up on my screen in the simulator. My current code:

```swift
import UIKit
import PassKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addWalletButton()

    }

    private func addWalletButton() {
        let passButton =  PKAddPassButton(addPassButtonStyle: PKAddPassButtonStyle.black)
        passButton.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(passButton)
    }

}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your button has no bounds.

Try:

```
let passButton = PKAddPassButton(addPassButtonStyle: PKAddPassButtonStyle.black)
passButton.frame = CGRect(x:  (UIScreen.main.bounds.width-280)/2, y: 150, width: 280, height: 60)
passButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(passButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
view.addSubview(passButton)
```

Adjust the size and position to suit your app.  And don't forget to add an action so it does something when tapped.

Comment: Remove the addTarget line if you haven’t set an action function yet, then replace the code in your addWalletButton function.