# What Swift Framework Lets You Create Apple Wallet Buttons?

Tags: swift

I am trying to create an Apple Wallet button in my app that lets someone add a pass to an event to their Apple Wallet. What framework will let us do this?

I tried playing around with UIKit but can't find any references to creating cards.

Comment: [Add to Apple Wallet Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/wallet/add-to-apple-wallet-guidelines/) could be useful, [`PKAddPassButton`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkaddpassbutton) is what you're probably looking for, [How to add "Add to Apple Wallet" button with PKAddPassButton - swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56214544/how-to-add-add-to-apple-wallet-button-with-pkaddpassbutton-swift) will probably help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's PassKit / PassBook framework is what you are looking for.